# Place for indie developers to promote their own software

Tags: feature-request, self-promotion

Within the Stack Exchange ecosystem, is there a place for indie developers to post links to their software? Promote, test, discuss, and brag about it? If no, then why not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is there a place for indie developers to post links to their software? Promote, Test, Discuss, and Brag about it?

Sure. Your user profile on any of the sites.

Additionally, specifically on Stack Overflow you have your developer story - that's one of the big points of the developer story - it gives you a place to tell everyone about your achievements and things you have done (that don't fall under a traditional CV).

Comment: And it even has SEO juice - above a certain number of reputation points(?).

Answer (score 8):

There is one place where you can place links to your projects and company, and even promote your own services: the user profile's *about me* section, or the Developer Story on Stack Overflow.

There might be some chat rooms where such discussions are allowed, but I am not aware of any of them.

The rest of Stack Exchange is just questions and answers. No place for advertisement, discussions, etc.

Comment: Well, except for the developer story - great place for such a thing.

Comment: Of course, SO has the Developer Story. Another good place!

Comment: A nitpicker might say that the OP asks for such place for a specific group of developers while all options offered in this answer are for open for ALL developers. Luckily I'm not a nitpicker ...

Comment: That is true. SE doesn't differentiate based on the type of developer. @rene